# Split and rename the splitted files in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i used below command to spit the file

```
split -l 100 date.csv date.csv
```

The files are splittes as below

```
date.csvaa
date.csvab
date.csvac
date.csvad
date.csvae
```

I want to rename the files as below.

```
date_1.csv
date_2.csv
date_3.csv
date_4.csv
date_5.csv
```

please help

Comment: From `man split` ---> `--additional-suffix=SUFFIX /// append an additional SUFFIX to file names.` Or also `-d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM] // use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways of approaching this. Other answers provide a way to do it just with arguments passed to `split` - however the version of split on ubuntu 12.04 don't appear to support the arguments used in those answers.

Here is one. This splits the files and uses the default option on `split` to prefix the file names with an `x`. It then lists the files in order and renames them as required.

```
    split -l 100 date.csv
    i=1
    for x in `ls x* | sort`
    do
        mv $x date_$i.csv
        i=$(($i+1))
    done
```

Answer (score 10):

this line does it in one-shot:

```
split --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.csv -l100 data.csv data_
```

little test (from stdin):

```
kent$  split --version|head -1
split (GNU coreutils) 8.22

kent$  l   
total 0

kent$  seq 10|split --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.csv -l2 - data_      

kent$  l
total 20K
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 4 Mar 14 11:13 data_01.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 4 Mar 14 11:13 data_02.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 4 Mar 14 11:13 data_03.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 4 Mar 14 11:13 data_04.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 kent kent 5 Mar 14 11:13 data_05.csv
```

Comment: what version of split is this for? On ubuntu 12.04, with coreutils 8.12.197-032bb 'additional-suffix' is not a recognised option, nor does 'numeric-suffixes' accept an argument

Comment: I don't have ubuntu. my split has version: `split (GNU coreutils) 8.22` @knolleary

Comment: Ok, your answer is much nicer... if you have a recent enough version of split :)

Comment: --additional-suffix added in coreutils-8.16, also --numeric-suffixes taking a starting number (1 in this case not 0) was added in coreutils-8.16 (March 2012)