# split command with user defind prefix and suffix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a file `file_Md.csv` with more than `5000` lines in it. So I wanted to split the original file into multiple files with `2000` lines each. But the result files should have prefix as `file_Md` and suffix as `.csv`.

Example 
`file_Mda.csv` , `file_Mdb.csv` like wise.

So for this I used the below command to prefix
`split -l 2000 -a 1 file_Md.csv file_Md`

Could any one help me with suffix part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split and rename the splitted files in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401622/split-and-rename-the-splitted-files-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `split` is not having `--additional-suffix` option available ,here is one `awk` solution:

General solution: for number increment: User need to add the value of prefix ,suffix and number of lines to do partition with.

```
awk -v N=1 -v pre="file_Md" -v suf=".csv" -v line=4000 'NR%line==1{x=pre N suf ;N++} {print > x}' filename
```

Genreral solution for alphabets increment:

```
awk -v pre="file_Md" -v suf=".csv" -v line=4000 'BEGIN{split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",A,"");} NR%line==1{x=pre A[N] suf ;N++}{print > x}' filename
```

Hardcoded solution for your case:

```
awk 'BEGIN {  split("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", A, "");} NR%4000==1{x="file_Md" A[N] ".csv";N++}{print > x}' file_Md.csv
```

Example: Files before running the command:

```
 ls -1
total 28K
file_Md.csv
```

Files after Executing the command:

```
sh-4.1$ ls -1
file_Md.csv  # this is orignal file
file_MdA.csv
file_MdB.csv
file_MdC.csv
file_MdD.csv
file_MdE.csv
```

If you just want to increment by numbers:

```
awk -v N=1 'NR%4000==1{x="file_Md" N".csv";N++} {print > x}' file_Md.csv
```

*Explanation : `NR%4000` will find out the lines which are divisible by 4000. So take further action of them. 
Define a variable `x` which is set to `"file_Md"` then `a[N]` and finally `.csv`,which is generated from `split` function.

`split` function is splitting A-Z into individual letters. It would be lot simple if you use number instead of Alphas.*

Comment: Nice approach! Could try moving the `file_Md` string as an `awk` variable, there by making the command more generic & enabling the to user have control over the processing he needs to do.

Comment: Thank You!!! If this is simple using number then could you please tell me how to do using number?

Comment: check update in above answer.

Comment: Just one question. Since I need 2000 lines with each file I will have to give `NR%2000` right?

Comment: yes...................... ,you can verify that using `wc -l file`

Comment: Thank you. it's working.

Comment: When I substitute a variable instead of `file_Md` as `awk -v N=1 'NR%1000000==1{x=${SplitFile} N".csv";N++} {print > x}' ${FILENAME}
` I am getting syntax error. Any help

Comment: you are trying to use bash variable `SplitFile` inside awk. Which will not work. To make it work you need to define the value of `SplitFile` at the start of awk invokation. something like this `awk -v SplitFile="file_md" 'rest of awk command'`

Comment: something like this :`awk -v N=1 -v SplitFile="file_Md" 'NR%100==1{x=SplitFile N".csv";N++} {print > x}' ${FILENAME}`

Comment: But prefix value is a variable like `${prefix}` i.e `SplitFile=${prefix}` so I cannot hard code in the above command. So with out hard coding it how can I do it?

Comment: `awk -v SplitFile="$prefix" ..............`. should work

Comment: @Inian done. thanks for suggestion.